# Android Webview HTML Fixed Element overflow-x:hidden Not Working

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, css-position

I have a `position:fixed` Element A that contains Element B that's much wider and sometimes taller than A. I set Element A to `overflow-x:hidden` to prevent scrolling in the horizontal direction but it's not working. This issue doesn't occur in iOS's UIWebview.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to user fixed position in Mobile browsers.

There's many issues about this feature in mobile phone and it does not support currently before android version 3 (http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed).

I suggest that you change your design with combination of absolute+relative positioning